# Iron router not displaying notFound page

Tags: meteor, iron-router

**TL,DR:** How to make the not found template work within a global layout template given the router is running on the client side only (this is a requirement: client and server routes are separated.)

I need iron:router to display a default template when it couldn't match any router.
In my app, all routers are client side (the router.js file is inside the client folder.)
So far, this is what my code looks like:

1. **router.js - client side**

```html
Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate: 'ApplicationLayout'
});

Router.map(function() {
    this.route('home', {
        path: '/',

        onAfterAction: function() {
            document.title = 'MyApp';
        },

        action: function() {
            this.render('Home');
            this.render('Menu', {to: 'menu'});
            this.render('Footer', {to: 'footer'});
        } 
    });

    this.route('notFound', {
        path: '*',

        onAfterAction: function() {
            document.title = 'Page not found - MyApp';
        },

        action: function() {
            this.render('NotFound');
            this.render('Menu', {to: 'menu'});
            this.render('Footer', {to: 'footer'});
        }

    });
});
```

2. **ApplicationLayout.html**

```html
<template name="ApplicationLayout">
      
  <div class="nav-container">
    {{> yield "menu"}}
  </div>

  <div class="main-container">
    {{> yield}}
  </div>

  <div class="footer-container">
    {{> yield "footer"}}
  </div>

</template>
```

Reading the docs at http://eventedmind.github.io/iron-router/#404s-and-client-vs-server-routes, it appears the server sends a `404` but it wasn't. So I made another router on the server side that sends a `404` but even that fixed nothing.

3. **router.js - server side**

```html
Router.map(function() {
    this.route('notFound', {
        path: '*',

        action: function() {
            this.response.statusCode = 404;
            this.response.end();
        }
    }); 
});
```

**Result so far:**
`Oops, looks like there's no route on the client or the server for url: "http://localhost:3000/logi/."`

**Other attempts:**
I tried including a `notFoundTemplate` in the global router configuration and *it did display* the `NotFound` template but <s>*not within* the `layoutTemplate`</s> the `Menu` and `Footer` templates are not loaded. But if I understand correctly, such template is called when the `data` function  returns `null` -  https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/issues/116, see answer by *cmather*.

**Relevant details:**

1. meteor@1.0.3.1
2. iron:router@1.0.7

#### EDIT

Using the `notFoundTemplate` property in the configuration *does show* the  `NotFound` template but omits the `Menu` and `Footer` templates.

Answer (score 6):

All you need is this:

> Define your general templates in the Router configuration (server and client location)

```
Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: "MasterLayout",
  loadingTemplate: "Loading",
  notFoundTemplate: "NotFound"
});
```

> Define your general templates under the client folder

```
<template name="NotFound">
  Ups... nobody here?
</template>

<template name="Loading">
  Loading awesome things...
</template>

<template name="MasterLayout">
    <div layout horizontal center-center fit id="content">
        {{> yield}}
    </div>
</template>
```

> The try to navigate for example to http://localhost:3000/nothinghereyet which should return **Ups... nobody here?**

Comment: Yes, I did that and it does show the `NotFound` template but the `Menu` and `Footer` templates are not being shown which breaks the design. To reproduce the problem, add another template that must be loaded alongside the `NotFound` template, like say a menu. Any suggestions on how to solve that?

Comment: Which version of iron:router are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Ok then please try that and let me know if it worked:

```
<template name="NotFound">

  <div class="nav-container">
    {{> yield "menu"}}
  </div>

  Ups... nobody here?

  <div class="footer-container">
    {{> yield "footer"}}
  </div>

</template>
```

Comment: No that didn't work either. IronRouter is able to use the `ApplicationLayout` and inject the `NotFound` template but it just can't display the menu and footer. So in this case (the current answer), it injecting the HTML but it just can't seem to find the menu and the footer so they're empty.

Answer (score 1):

I've create a small sample project to show you that it is working as described above. Let me know if it helped.

https://github.com/meteorpoly/sof-iron-router-sample